Why is my Android device not being recognized by adb on Windows 11?
I'm trying to use adb on Windows 11 and it's not picking up any of my devices. I've tried both a Samsung Galaxy S24 Ultra and a Google Pixel 6a.
I've downloaded the platform tools on Windows 11 and added adb to my path so there's no problem there, adb is working just fine. I've enabled developer options on both phones and enabled USB debugging as well, my default USB configuration is set to file transfer even though I've tried every USB configuration available and I'm using the appropriate USB-C cable.
I have even tried different usb ports on my computer as I have 3 of them. However, when I enable usb debugging I'm not getting the normal popup for the computer's RSA fingerprint asking me to allow access to the phones so what could I be doing wrong? I've never had this problem before, normally I do all that I listed above and adb works just fine.
I've scoured the internet for solutions but they are all the same and no matter what I try I cannot get adb to recognize the devices. I've even gone as far as downloading specific USB drivers for each phone with no success. I'm at a loss, could windows defender somehow be blocking the adb connection?
Would my firewall somehow be contributing to the problem? I only have the stock Windows Defender options enabled and have not messed with the firewall in any way.

I think this belongs on the Superuser site.  Its not really about android?

When you have device problems the first check shoould always be Windows Device Manager. Is the adb device (often named "Android Composite ADB Interface
") visible in there? If not all the tests you made are useless because without a working adb device driver nothing can work.

Last time I had this, the problem was that Windows 11 wasn't seeing the USB ports. Does any another USB device work? If not, try a full shut down and restart of Windows. My problem proved to be specific to this 2-in-1 laptop: the CPU is part of the dismountable screen/tablet and un- then re-docking it with the keyboard, which has the USB sockets fixed the problem.

Yes, all of the USB ports are working, I tried every one with a double for a mouse and they are all fine. I will check the windows device manager and get back to you, however I did download the USB drivers for each phone before hand, does that make a difference?

So im not finding "Android Composite ADB Interface" in the windows device manager. How do i go about fixing that?

I fixed it, it was as simple as restarting my computer. Idk what exactly the problem was, but its working now.
